# Ajax Django Request Returns 403 On Mobile, But Not Desktop

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, csrf

I have a Django website which uses ajax. Specifically, i'm using an ajax POST request.

The request works fine on my computer, but returns a 403 Forbidden on my cell phone (android Samsung galaxy 3). The CSRF token is passed as described in the documentation, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Or any ideas as to what is the problem.

Comment: Could you add your javascript code, please?